# why does for each loop showing an extra zeroes?

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach

[*arrays that showing an extra zeroes*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBxji.jpg)

dsaf sdf sdf sdf sd;iofj sadoifj sodfji sodijfosdijfosidjfos dijfosdijfsodifj sodifjsodifjsodifjsodi jsodfij osdifjsodifjsodifjosdifjsodif js

Comment: because you initialize `marks` as `new int [5]` and not `new int [3]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and tag a language ([tag:java]). See also: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

When you initialized **marks** created it as **new int[5]** when it should be **new int [3]** thats why you have 2 extra zeros